# Articles dissapearing after JUpdate 1.5-2.5 Joomla

Tags: joomla

After i update my joomla 1.5 - 2.5 using JUpdate my articles sections isnt shown on my site,
the menu and the pages itself are but the articles are only shown in the backend.

Is there any way to make them visible again ? is there anything i did wrong or do i just need to link them again ? (no idea how joomla is new for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a menu item linked to an article? If so then i would look in your template's index.php. Make sure

'jdoc:include type="component" '

Gets run

Comment: I got this in my joomla panel ------
Public  Articles » Featured Articles --- so i think its linked . where should i include component ? in the main content area?

Comment: If you are using a featured articles menu item then make sure you have featured articles otherwise there will be no content

Comment: ok thanx alot for the help, the jdoc include can be placed anywhere within the index.php document? or does it need some special placing (example in de content area ?)

Comment: it must be in the html body. But i still think it is your menu item which is not set up correctly.

Comment: To test create a new menu item and select single article and choose an existing article. Then go that page by clicking on new link in the menu and the article should be there.

Comment: mmm also my active menu link isnt showing proper css for the class... i will check the setup of the menu again, if thats it ill come back to accept answer ;) already much thanx

Comment: Ahh checked it both arent working ... new menu also doesnt show the articles and adding the link in my index.php isnt the trick also ... fml

Comment: Would be awesome if u got any idea what else could be wrong

Comment: Only other thing i can think of doing is to try to use the default template which came with joomla 2.5) and see if the content is showing up. If that doesnt work then try disabling any plugins which may be overriding something.